# Using DateTime in PHP, generating bad unix epoch time from $foo->format('U')

Tags: php, datetime, time, epoch

I can't seem to get the correct Unix epoch time out of this PHP DateTime object.

> $startingDateTime = "2005/08/15 1:52:01 am";
>
> $foo = new DateTime($startingDateTime, new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
>
> echo $foo->format('U');

which gives

> 1124085121

Which is Mon, 15 Aug 2005 00:52:01 GMT -500 (according to [EPOCH CONVERTER](http://www.epochconverter.com/)) but that's incorrect by an hour.

It SHOULD be 1124088721 and spit back at me as Mon, 15 Aug 2005 01:52:01 GMT -500

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a DST problem with epoch converter.  I used another [converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) to UTC time and [then](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?month=8&day=15&year=2005&hour=5&min=50&sec=0&p1=0&p2=179) to America/New_York.  I got the right answer given `timestamp=1124085121`

Comment: I think you're right. The problem ended up being on the back end when I was trying to fetch out the data and redisplay it to the screen from the database. Was making a new DateTime object and passing it the UTC timestamp AND a timezone. The DateTime object with the data to be displayed was interpreting the UTC timestamp as though it had an offset when it didn't